# Spotlight keyboard shortcut broken

Tags: keyboard, macos, spotlight

I installed and removed Quicksilver and since that time the keyboard shortcut for Spotlight has not been working. I mean when I press cmd + space it should open spotlight search bar.
I've been into Keyboard Settings > Shortcuts > Spotlight and it is correctly set to cmd + space. I've tried changing it to another setting and then back and also by pressing the 'Restore Defaults' button on the page but nothing has helped.

I can access the spotlight search if I mouse click the magnifying glass in the menu bar so I know the spotlight search feature is still there and working. But pressing cmd + space right now does nothing.

How can I get the shortcut working again? Maybe there's something I can type in the terminal that could help?

Comment: Does it still show as enabled in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Spotlight ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, just coming back to this now (have been putting up with it recently). Yes it still shows as enabled.

Comment: Update: I never did get this working. I installed Alfred and have used its features as a stand in ever since. It's been almost 4 years.